# how to use boost in_state_reaction

Tags: boost, boost-statechart

I'm trying to use `in_state_reaction`.
Oddly the react function for this doesn't seem to be executed after `process_event ()` is called.
I changed `in_state_reaction` to `custom_reaction` and it seems fine.

Just want to know how do I make it work with `in_state_reaction`.
I must be doing something wrong.

I'd appriciate sample codes. Not a lot samples out there for in-state.

Thanks.

```
struct Reset : sc::simple_state<Reset, Idle>
{
    Reset() {  }
    ~Reset() {  }


    typedef sc::in_state_reaction<Event1> reactions;


    sc::result react(const Event1 &)
    {
              printf ("In state reaction\n");
        return discard_event();
    } // react

}; // Reset
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in_state_reaction` is not a custom reaction, so `react` wouldn't be called!
In-state reaction means that you want to invoke some function and to keep staying in the same state.

`in_state_reaction<Event1, Context, &Context::doSomething>`

Use custom reaction when you can't know in compile-time what your destination state is.